# Javascript - change style by class - onmouse

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, onmouseover, getelementsbyclassname

i want to change the Style of all Classes by an mouseover / mouseout event.

```js
var shadow = document.getElementsByClassName('shadow-primary');


for (var k = 0; k < shadow.length; k++) {
  var hi = shadow[k]
  hi.onmouseover = function() {
    hi.style["box-shadow"] = "10px 10px 10px #1D618C, 5px 5px 5px #1D618C";
    //console.log(hi);
  }
  hi.onmouseout = function() {
    hi.style["box-shadow"] = "none";
    //console.log(hi);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary shadow-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">TESTING</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <strong>TEST0</strong>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>

<div class="panel panel-primary shadow-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">TESTING</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <strong>TEST1</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Problem is as you can see in the Code Snippet.
Cause of my bad coded for loop just the last array is doing what i want.

Could you tell me how it is possible to doing the code Work with all Elements with the Class "shadow-primary".

Please no answers how to do that with an HTML Event Handler.
TY :)

Comment: How about answers that show how to do it with just CSS?

Comment: No i know how to 'hover' but thats not the answer i am looking for.

Comment: Use this Code:

var shadow = document.querySelectorAll('.shadow-primary');
console.log(shadow);
for (let k = 0; k < shadow.length; k++) {
  var hi = shadow[k]
  hi.onmouseover = function() {
    hi.style["box-shadow"] = "10px 10px 10px #1D618C, 5px 5px 5px #1D618C";
    console.log(hi);
  }
  hi.onmouseout = function() {
    hi.style["box-shadow"] = "none";
    //console.log(hi);
  }
}